# How read continuously updating file using pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

For a POC we are creating an architecture where the data from the on-premises database is replicated to AWS S3 in parquet format (continuous replication using CDC). The parquet file is then read and transformed using a pyspark script running in AWS glue for further use. However, we have the following concern,

1. Will the continuous write to the parquet file from the data replicator engine cause access/performance problem for the pyspark script ?
2. Is it possible to extract snapshot from the parquet file and perform the transformation operation on the snapshot. How to automate the incremental snapshot creation from the parquet file?

The current implementation is behaving inconsistently but that is mostly due to malformed parquet file

Comment: S3 writes are atomic, so if you think you're appending to an existing file, you're not. Either you're rewriting the entire file (which will delete earlier data unless you're actually doing a full dump every time), or you're actually writing multiple files over time.

Comment: Considering the above mentioned behavior of S3, our concern is how the glue script will react if,
1. S3 deletes the file while the script was reading it
2. S3 deletes the file right before the script tries to read it

Comment: As I said, S3 operations are atomic. In case #1, if the GET succeeds then you will be able to read the entire file. In case #2, if the GET occurs after the file was deleted, then you'll get a 404. Case #3, which you didn't consider, is that the file is replaced and you lose access to its former contents. And case #4 is that you're doing byte-range retrievals, and you get some bytes from the old version and some bytes from the new.

Comment: Bottom line: revisit your architecture, because this one is fundamentally flawed.